# How do I specify the name of the packages.yml file in the dbt deps command?

Tags: package, dbt

I have 2 packages.yml file in my project directory to address my use case. The files are as below:

- packages.yml
- packages_1.yml

Each of the above 2 packages files have different packages with different versions.

Therefore how do I specify the names of the packages.yml file in my dbt deps command?

I have tried using the following commands:

```
dbt deps --profiles-dir ${DBT_PROFILES_DIR} --project-dir ${DBT_PROJECT_DIR} packages.yml
dbt deps --profiles-dir ${DBT_PROFILES_DIR} --project-dir ${DBT_PROJECT_DIR} packages_1.yml
```

I expected the dbt deps command to pick up the packages.yml files from my project directory and install the packages.

However this doesn't seem to work. It only picks up the first one.

Comment: You can’t. The dependency file must be called packages.yml.

Comment: Adam is correct, but I'm curious as to what you're trying to achieve and why? It's possible there's a better approach.